# Does a SKTexture from a SKTextureAtlas support the mipmap feature?

Tags: sprite-kit, mipmaps, sktexture, sktextureatlas

From apples documentation:
"You can only request mipmaps if both of the texture’s dimensions are a power of two."

However, it's unclear whether the SKTextures from SKTextureAtlas's also support this feature (since they're essentially a bit different in nature).

I ask the question because it's actually hard to see if anything is getting mipmapped from the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off a SKTexture from a SKTextureAtlas does not support mipmapping. Secondly sometimes mipmapping doesn't even work with a regular SKTexture it depends a lot on how it is nested inside the node structure.